# compare distribution of questions on topics (Values to rows)

Tags: python, compare

I have a LDAmodel and some data (at the moment 50k questions). When I run the model, it makes topics and puts every question in a topics. In this example there are 20 topics.

For each question I can find the distribution over the topics because most questions don't fit 100% to 1 topic.

What I would like to do is to compare each question to the other questions to look for similarity so I can select questions that are almost the same.

I take a small portion of the questions and there distribution:

```
words = {'00': [0,0,35,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],'01': [0,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
'02': [0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],'03': [0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,],
'04': [0,0,0,0,0,0,28,0,0,0,],'05': [0,0,0,0,97,0,0,0,0,0,],
'06': [19,0,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],'07': [0,0,0,25,0,0,41,0,56,38,],
'08': [0,0,0,54,0,0,0,0,0,0,],'09': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,0,],
'10': [0,0,0,16,1,0,0,0,0,0,],'11': [0,0,0,0,0,99,0,0,0,0,],
'12': [79,0,0,0,0,0,0,35,0,0,],'13': [0,57,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
'14': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,], '15': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],
'16': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,54,],'17': [0,21,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,0,],
'18': [0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,0,0,],'19': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,]}
dfwords = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(words)
```

At the moment I have a loop to compare each question to all the others. It loops each question "I" over all the other questions "J" and calculates the difference in score for each topic "K". For each question "J" there is a some of differences "K" and the questions with the lowest score does look most alike.

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(Question), len(Question)))) 
for i in range(len(Question)):
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(Question), 1)))
    df3.rename(columns={0:str(i)}, inplace=True)
    for j in range(len(Question)):
        indnum = 0
        for k in range(Topic_num):
            indnum+=abs((dfwords.iat[j, k]-dfwords.iat[i, k]))
        df3.iat[j,0]=indnum
    df4[i] = df3[str(i)]
```

It works but this is really brute force and I am sure there are a lot of smarter ways to do this but at the moment I can't figure them out. I have xy coordinates for each topic so I was thinking to do something with that but I'm not sure how.

It has to be smarter to prefend 50k times 50k times 20 comparisons and to make it better accessible then a 50k times 50k table.

Can anyone help me with this, maybe just point me in the right direction? Any help would really be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I switched to numpy and got way better performance.

Example that works for me:

```
pattern = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(20,numCols))
for i in range(pattern.shape[0]):
    for j in range(pattern.shape[0]):
        differ = sum(abs(pattern[i,:] - pattern [j,:]))
        if j == 0:
            tempnp = np.array([[differ]])
        else:
            tempnp = np.append(tempnp,[[differ]],axis=1)
        sum(abs(pattern[i,:] - pattern [j,:]))
    if i == 0:
        finalnp = np.array(tempnp)
    else:
        finalnp = np.append(finalnp,tempnp,axis=0)
```

But still I have the feeling this can be optimized a lot..